# Оптимизация решения задачи на перестановки

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада, комбинаторика

Нужно вывести на экран все сочетания с повторениями чисел от 0 до n длины n, сумма чисел в которых кратна `n+1`. Например, при `n=3`, программа должна вывести:

```
0 0 0
0 1 3
0 2 2
1 1 2
2 3 3
```

Вот решение полным перебором:

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

n = int(input())
arr = range(0, n + 1)

for i in cwr(arr, n):
    if sum(i) % (n + 1) == 0:
        print(*i)
```

Для небольших n оно выполняется достаточно быстро, но все же не является оптимальным. За счет чего его можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Одно из упрощений - для числа n Вам нужно перебрать n комбинаций: 0 n+1, 2(n+1), 3(n+1) ... n*(n+1). К примеру, для 2: 0 3, для 3; 0, 4, 8, для 4 0, 5, 10, 15. В идеале Вы должны теперь для n чисел распределить в каждой итерации сумму. Однако нужно подумать над распределением для чисел не с одним знаком. //не знаю как объяснить лучше.

Comment: Для n>9 будут комбинации вроде   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 8 11  (n=12) ?

Comment: @MBo, да, но это не будет верным ответом

Comment: А как надо - только однозначные числа или что?  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 10 - правильная комбинация?  Я почему спрашивал - не все различают цифры и числа...

Comment: Ага, увидел исправление

Comment: В этой задаче есть какая-то хитрая комбинаторика, которая, видимо, позволит создавать нужные комбинации без перебора.

Answer (score 3):

Задача о наборе суммы с ограничением слагаемых и их числа. Рекурсивное решение.

Возможные дальнейшие оптимизации:

- избавиться от перераспределения списка `a[]`, сделать его глобальным, заполнять неиспользованый остаток нулями
- вызывать `calсsum` в цикле только для тех значений `i`, для которых есть шанс получить решение (ограничения в `range` и сверху, и снизу)

---

```
def calcsum(s, idx, maxx, n, a):
    if s == 0:
        for i in range(idx, n):
            a[i] = 0
        print(a)
        return
    if idx >= n:
        return
    for i in range(min(s, maxx), 0, -1):
        a[idx] = i
        calcsum(s - i, idx + 1, i, n, a)

def nsums(n):
    a = [0]*n
    for t in range(n * n  // (n + 1) + 1):
        s = t * (n + 1)
        calcsum(s, 0, n, n, a)

nsums(3)

>>>
[0, 0, 0]
[3, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Ваш вариант в четыре раза медленее оригинального. `n = 12, 13`. Я пока не понимаю в чем дело.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Например, функция из itertools может быть на С

Comment: Вы правы: 1: у автора отличная константа. 2: программе надо выводит так много данных что её особо не улучшишь.

Answer (score 3):

Сперва решим другой вопрос: как сильно можно оптимизировать решение задачи?

Текущее решение имеет сложность `Cnk(2n, n) * n`. Первый множитель - число сочетаний с повторениями, если длина сочетания `n`, а количество элементов в множестве `n + 1`. Второй множитель - вызов функции `sum` для списка из `n` элементов. Сложности проверки суммы и печати тоже укладываются в `n`.

Насколько может быть улучшена эта сложность? Для оценки я воспользуюсь фактом: сложность алгоритма не может быть лучше чем объём результата работы. Факт почти очевиден если примем что для печати одного элемента результата нужно постоянное время. Объём результата равен `(Cnk(2n, n) / (n + 1)) * n`. Первый множитель - число комбинаций у которых сумма делится на `n + 1` (это можно доказать, я опускаю доказательство для краткости). Второй множитель - длина сочетания.

Собирая вместе обе оценки можно сказать: ваш алгоритм работает в `n + 1` раз медленнее чем мог бы. Много это или мало? Скорее мало: объём печати растёт с `n` экспоненциально: если `n` увеличивается на единицу, количество сочетаний возрастает примерно в четыре раза.
Уже для `n = 16` время работы - минуты, для `n = 19` - часы, для `n = 21` - дни.

Если О-большое улучшить можно, константу скорее всего нет. Ваше решение очень простое. Почти весь код который работает в цикле написан на `C` и исполняется очень быстро - раз в десять-пятьдесят быстрее чем если бы он был написан на Питоне.

Код ниже имеет оптимальную сложность `(Cnk(2n, n) / (n + 1)) * n` (в терминах О-большого лучше написать `Cnk(2n, n)`):

```
def print_combinations(n):
     a = [0] * n

    def search(i, min_term, target):
        if i == n:
            print(*a)
            return

        r = range(max(min_term, target - (n - i - 1) * n), target // (n - i) + 1)
        assert len(r) > 0
        for term in r:
            a[i] = term
            search(i + 1, term, target - term)

    for t in range(0, n * n, n + 1):
        search(0, 0, t)
```

Этот код следует идее из [ответа MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1313243/416121): печатать сочетания для разных сумм (`0`, `n + 1`, `2(n + 1)`, ...) отдельно.

Лес из деревьев вызовов функции `search` для `n = 4`:

> ```
> *           *                *           *
> |         /   \           /  |  \        |
> 0        0     1        0    1    2      3
> |       / \     \      /|   /|\   |      |
> 0      0   1     1    2 3  1 2 3  2      4
> |     /|   |\    |    | |  | | |  |\     |
> 0    1 2   1 2   1    4 3  4 3 3  2 3    4
> |    | |   | |   |    | |  | | |  | |    |
> 0    4 3   3 2   2    4 4  4 4 3  4 3    4
> ```

Во всех листьях `search` печатает сочетание - сложность `n`. Во внутренних узлах дерева время работы `search` пропорционально числу исходящих рёбер.

Оценим суммарное число рёбер во всех деревьях. Каждый путь в дереве завершается в листе (тоже самое можно сказать по другому - алгоритм не просматривает тупиковые поддеревья, про это `assert` в коде). Длина каждого пути в ребрах - `n`. Следовательно всего рёбер не более `<число листьев> * n`, а число листьев - это число комбинаций в результате: `Cnk(2n, n) / (n + 1)`.

Общее время обработки внутренних узлов леса `(Cnk(2n, n) / (n + 1)) * n`. Общее время печати сочетаний оценивается той же формулой. Следовательно сложность оптимальная. А константа не самая лучшая - много операций, все на Питоне.

Для сравнения времена работы двух вариантов. Оптимальный быстрее, но разница не такая большая из-за констант:

> ```
>       время работы    множитель       относительное
>  n   cwr_sum search   времени (с)      ускорение
>
>  1    1.38    2.28    *     0.0000001    0.61 
>  2    2.18    4.70    *     0.0000001    0.46 
>  3    4.94   11.3     *     0.0000001    0.44 
>  4    1.51    3.22    *     0.000001     0.47 
>  5    5.22    9.78    *     0.000001     0.53 
>  6    1.90    3.06    *     0.00001      0.62 
>  7    7.17   10.3     *     0.0001       0.70 
>  8    2.80    3.54    *     0.001        0.79 
>  9    1.15    1.24    *     0.01         0.93 
> 10    4.11    4.45    *     0.01         0.92 
> 11    1.66    1.58    *     0.1          1.05 
> 12    6.41    5.60    *     0.1          1.14 
> 13    2.63    2.03    *     1            1.30 
> 14   10.4     7.40    *     1            1.41 
> 15    4.19    2.75    *    10            1.52 
> 16    1.63    1.03    *   100            1.58 
> 17    6.60    3.83    *   100            1.72 
> 18    2.67    1.45    *  1000            1.84 
> 19   10.8     5.52    *  1000            1.96 
> 20    4.52    2.15    * 10000            2.10
> ```